# Closed set of infinite union

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A = \{0\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n}: n \geq 2\right\}$. Consider $$A_1 = A \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right): k \geq 2\right\}.$$
I'm basically constructing a sequence that approaches each point in $A$ from the right. Repeat this process; for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_{i+1}$ is the union of $A_i$ along with all the sequences that approach each point in $A_i$ from the right. Is it true that $\bigcup_{i \geq 1} A_i$ is closed?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your definiton, $\bigcup_{i\geq 1}A_{i}$ is not closed.

You can always construct a sequence of points by choosing one point $a_{i}$ from each $A_{i}$ (from the group of points that approach $a_{i-1}$). As long as you make each $a_{i}$ close enough to $a_{i-1}$, your sequence $\{a_{i}\}_{i\geq 1}$ will not converge to any point from any of the $A_{k}$'s.

More specifically, in *your* construction of the $A_{i}$'s, the sequence of points $\{\max A_{i}\}_{i\geq 1}$ converges to 1, but 1 is certainly not contained in any of your $A_{i}$'s.